# Issue importing env variables into edge function

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, supabase

I have a react client connected with supabase. My supabase connection is working correctly, as I have tested normal CRUD functionality between the database tables and the react client. However, I am needing some additional functionality to connect with third party APIs (such as Plaid and Stripe), so I am trying to set up these services in Supabase Edge Functions. Here is my EXAMPLE code (supabase/functions/test.index.ts):

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts";

console.log("Hello from Functions!");
console.log(Deno.env.get("STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY"));

serve(async (req) => {
  const { name } = await req.json();
  const data = {
    message: `Hello ${name}!`,
  };

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
});
```

Also, here is my .env file, which is in the same directory as the supabase folder (root directory):

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=123
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=456
```

Every time I serve the edge function, the 'STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY' is always undefined. However, if I were to log something like

```
console.log(Deno.env.get('SUPABASE_URL'));
```

this prints just fine (since it is a default env variable). I just cannot seem to figure out how to create and access custom env variables. What am I missing? Do I need to set up these env variables somewhere other than the .env file? Am I accessing them incorrectly? Please help!!

Comment: Did you use `supabase secrets set STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=123` with the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Remember in order to read env files in supabase edge functions you need to first initialise supabase. You could easily do it by tunning:

```
supabase init
```

it will ask you to generate VS code workspace settings. Say y

[image]

What I found helpful is instead of creating .env file you should directly set it with supabase cli.

```
supabase secrets set STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=123
```

Remember you might need to add npx in the start if you installed supabase cli inside your project.

```
npx supabase secrets set STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=123
```

And then you can access it with :

```
Deno.env.get('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY')
```